# Call to undefined method CI_Session::start()

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My current version of ci is 3.1.13. My PHP latest version is 7.3I added session library in config->autoload->libraries.

This is my controller for login

```
public function loginForm()
     {
         
          $arrLoginRules = array(
               array(
                    "field" => "user_id",
                    "label" => "User ID",
                    "rules" => "trim|required"
               ),
               array(
                    "field" => "pass",
                    "label" => "Institution Password",
                    "rules" => "trim|required"
               )
          );

          $this->form_validation->set_rules($arrLoginRules);

          if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
               
               $this->load->view('institution/institution_login', $data);
               
          } else {

              
               $user = $this->input->post('user_id');
               $password = md5($this->input->post('pass'));

               $user = $this->Institution_model->getInstitutionLoginDetails($user, $inst_type);

               if (!$user) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', 'Please check your User ID or Password and try again.', 300);
                    redirect(uri_string());
               }


               if ($password != $user->inst_password) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', 'Please check your email or password and try again.', 300);
                    redirect(uri_string());
               }

               $newdata = array(
                    'inst_code' => $user->inst_code,
                    'inst_name' => $user->inst_name,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE,
               );
               $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
               
               redirect('index.php/Institution'); // redirect to home

          }
     }
```

The session is set. Now my logged in function is belo:

```
public function index()
     {
          if(isset($_SESSION)){
               $this->session->start();
               print_r($_SESSION);die();
          }
          else{
               echo "bad";die();
          }
     }
```

The session is set. But not getting the session data. They are all blank.
[image: The output I am getting is :]

Comment: if i remove  $this->session->start(), I am getting session data having only this:  [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1686978146

Comment: Could anybody please help.